# ImageView setImageResource() method is not working inside Runnable()

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am facing a weird issue and I cannot understand why.

**Case 1:**

```
Runnable mGen = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
                //Randomly generate variable i (0 or 1 in this example case)
                imageView[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.firstimage);

                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        } finally {

            imageView[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mGen, 500);
        }
    }
};

void startRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRandomGen,500);
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mGen);
}
```

In this case, I don't visibly see the imageView image resource being set to *firstimage*.

But if I do this,

**Case 2:**

```
Runnable mGen = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
                if(prevI!=-1)//Don't perform this first time
                      imageView[prevI].setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage);

                //Randomly generate variable i (0 or 1 in this example case)
                imageView[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.firstimage);

                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        } finally {

            prevI = i;
            mHandler.postDelayed(mGen, 500);
        }
    }
};
void startRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRandomGen,500);
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mGen);
}
```

I can see both images being set to the imageViews as expected.

Basically, I am generating a random number (0 or 1, for simplicity here), and setting that imageView to some image(firstimage), and then back to original image(secondimage), and repeating this every fixed interval.

In the first case, I do the setting and resetting in the same run of the thread, while in the second case, I do the resetting of the previous run in the current run.

What is wrong with my code in **case 1**? How to rectify it?

Comment: why are you calling the run method of your runnable directly?

Comment: Changed that call to mHandler.postDelayed(mGen,500); Still not working for **Case 1**